Rank of the linear map of adjoint action $X\mapsto AX-XA$ is always even?
Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and $M_n(\mathbb F)$ denote the algebra of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb F$. In this answer here, for a fixed $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\big)\in M_2(\mathbb F)$, I defined a linear map $\mathrm{ad}_A\colon\, M_2(\mathbb F)\to M_2(\mathbb F)$ by $\mathrm{ad}_A(X)= AX-XA$ whose matrix w.r.t. $\{E_{11},E_{21},E_{12}, E_{22}\}$ turned out to be: $$ \pmatrix{0&b&-c&0\\c&d-a&0&-c\\-b&0&a-d&b\\0&-b&c&0}$$
and @TravisWillse observed that a row operation of swapping $R_2\leftrightarrow R_3$ will make it an alternating matrix i.e., a skew-symmetric matrix with zeroes on the main diagonal. And it is known that alternating matrices have even rank.
I did something similar for $3\times 3$ matrices. Fixed $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\\a_4&a_5&a_6\\a_7&a_8&a_9\end{smallmatrix}\big)\in M_3(\mathbb F)$ and then defined $\mathrm{ad}_A\colon\,M_3(\mathbb F)\to M_3(\mathbb F)$ by $\mathrm{ad}_A(X)= AX-XA$ whose matrix w.r.t. $\{E_{1k},E_{2k}, E_{3k}:k=1,2,3\}$ turned out to be:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{2} & a_{3} & -a_{4} & 0 & 0 & -a_{7} & 0 & 0\\
a_{4} & a_{5} -a_{1} & a_{6} & 0 & -a_{4} & 0 & 0 & -a_{7} & 0\\
a_{7} & a_{8} & a_{9} -a_{1} & 0 & 0 & -a_{4} & 0 & 0 & -a_{7}\\
-a_{2} & 0 & 0 & a_{1} -a_{5} & a_{2} & a_{3} & -a_{8} & 0 & 0\\
0 & -a_{2} & 0 & a_{4} & 0 & a_{6} & 0 & -a_{8} & 0\\
0 & 0 & -a_{2} & a_{7} & a_{8} & a_{9} -a_{5} & 0 & 0 & -a_{8}\\
-a_{3} & 0 & 0 & -a_{6} & 0 & 0 & a_{1} -a_{9} & a_{2} & a_{3}\\
0 & -a_{3} & 0 & 0 & -a_{6} & 0 & a_{4} & a_{5} -a_{9} & a_{6}\\
0 & 0 & -a_{3} & 0 & 0 & -a_{6} & a_{7} & a_{8} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
And guess what? This also turns out to be an alternating matrix after some row swaps! This leads me to conjecture that:

$\text{rank}(\mathrm{ad}_A)$ is even for every $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb F)$.

How do I prove this if this is true? I can't work with a $16\times 16$ matrix for $n=4$.

Here is an elementary proof. Let $\tau$ be the transpose map $X\mapsto X^T$. Since $\tau$ is invertible, $\operatorname{ad}_A$ and $L=\operatorname{ad}_A\circ\,\tau$ have the same rank. Now consider the bilinear map $B:(X,Y)\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(Y^TL(X))$. Using the cyclic property of matrix trace, we see that
$$
B(X,Y)=\operatorname{tr}(Y^TAX^T)-\operatorname{tr}(X^TAY^T)
$$
and $B(X,X)=0$ for all $X$. Hence $B$ is alternating and its matrix representation with respect to the standard basis of $M_n(\mathbb F)$ has an even rank. However, as $B(X,Y)=\operatorname{tr}(Y^TL(X))$, $B$ and $L$ have the same matrix representation. Hence $\operatorname{rank}\operatorname{ad}_A=\operatorname{rank}L$ is also even.
Remark. As $L=\operatorname{ad}_A\circ\,\tau$, when the columns of the matrix of $\operatorname{ad}_A$ are scrambled appropriately (according to the permutation matrix, known as a commutation matrix, that represents $\tau$), the result will be a hollow skew-symmetric matrix (that represents $L$ and $B$). This is the reason behind the observation mentioned by the OP.

Very nice explanation! BTW, it does make sense to call $\tau$ a transposition map... Not because it "transposes" a matrix but because it represents a permutation of order two...

@Nothingspecial Uhh, sorry, but I did mean “transpose”. When $n=3$, the matrix of $\tau$ is a $9\times 9$ symmetric permutation matrix that represents a product of three disjoint “transpositions” ($2$-cycles) $(2,4),(3,7)$ and $(6,8)$. It is not a single transposition in the permutation sense.

Oh right! Sorry, I normally associate the symbol $\tau$ with a two-cycle i.e., a transposition. And for some reason, I conflated transpositions with permutations of order two. And this led me to make up that nonsense. Thank you for the clarification.

In terms of Lie algebras, the adjoint operators $ad(x)$ for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb F)$ preserve the Killing form, which is symmetric, bilinear and non-degenerate. Thus the rank of $ad(x)$ is even.
The Lie algebra of $M_n(K)$ is $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb F)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb F)\oplus \Bbb F$, where $\Bbb F$ is the center (so has $ad(x)=0$ for $x$ in the center).

I use the notation $\mathrm{ad}_x$ so I was a bit confused... The Killing form is $K(v,w) = \text{tr}(\mathrm{ad}_v\circ \mathrm{ad}_w)$. Now, what is meant by $T=\mathrm{ad}_x$ preserves the Killing form is that $K(v,w)=K(Tv, Tw)$. Is this right? How does this imply that rank of $T$ is even? I cannot follow.

For $T=Ad_x$, yes, see here. And ad-invariant means $K(ad_x(y),z)+K(y,ad_x(z))=0$ for all $x,y,z$.
